# Multi page form, back button to change state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have multi page form that has a back button built in. I want to change state when chapterID reaches 0.

$state.go executes but then redirects back to gn.newChapter state

HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="gn.newChapter({chapterID: id})" class="btn btn-primary"    ng-click="goBack()">Go Back</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.goBack = function() {
  if (newChapterService.getChapterState() === 0) {
    $state.go('gn.createGNForm');
  }
  else {
    $scope.id = newChapterService.goBackChapter();  
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"    ng-click="goBack()">Go Back</a>



$scope.goBack = function() {
  if (newChapterService.getChapterState() === 0) {
    $state.go('gn.createGNForm');
  }
  else {
    $scope.id = newChapterService.goBackChapter();  
    $state.go('gn.newChapter({chapterID: $scope.id})'); // I don't know your predefined paths. so just suggesting this as an answer. This line might be different according to your need.
  }
};
```